# d3: duplicating paths with more dimensional array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I replicated the [spline example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4342190) with following points (instead of random points):

```
var points = [[75, 15], [104, 80], [275, 80], [300, 15]];
```

It works perfect.
Now I want to draw two paths (all draggable as well) with following nodes:

```
var points = [ 
    [[75, 15], [104, 80], [275, 80], [300, 15]], 
    [[50, 20], [50, 100], [200, 200], [100, 300]] 
];
```

I get to draw the first path perfectly with selecting the first array:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(points[0])
    .attr("class", "anchorPointPath")
    .call(reDraw);
```

...but I can't get it to draw both paths! Appreciate any help for a d3 beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change how you add the paths:

```
svg.selectAll("path").data(points).enter().append("path")
    .datum(function(d) { return d;})
    .attr("class", "line")
    .call(redraw);
```

This takes the two points array, and add a path for every array inside of it. For each on of those sub arrays it binds the data of that array `return d;`.

On the redraw function, change `svg.select("path")` to `svg.selectAll("path")`, in order to select all of the path elements.

In addition when you add the circles, you can take all of the points and convert them into a one dimension array:

```
var circles = points.reduce(function(t, c) {
    return t.concat(c)
  });
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles, function(d) { return d; });
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgutVQhNzJNKxUuKmqyi?p=preview).

Comment: **Thank you**! I will read more about selections and understand my errors! This array reducing functions looks interesting - I will play a little bit with it.